# How can I replace all occurrences of a dollar ($) with an underscore (_) in javascript?

Tags: javascript, replace

As the title states, I need to relace all occurrences of the $ sign in a string variable with an underscore.

I have tried:

```
str.replace(new RegExp('$', 'g'), '_');
```

But this doesn't work for me and nothing gets replaced.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The `$` in RegExp is a special character, so you need to escape it with backslash.

```
new_str = str.replace(new RegExp('\\$', 'g'), '_');
```

however, in JS you can use the simpler syntax

```
new_str = str.replace(/\$/g, '_');
```

Comment: +1, go for the literal, don't bother with the constructor unless you need to use variables in regular expressions.

Answer (score 10):

You don’t need to use `RegExp`. You can use the literal syntax:

```
str.replace(/\$/g, '_')
```

You just need to escape the `$` character as it’s a special character in regular expressions that marks the end of the string.

---

**Edit**    Oh, you can also use `split` and `join` to solve this:

```
str.split("$").join("_")
```

Comment: Like the split and join idea – how fast is it in comparison with a regex I wonder?

Answer (score 1):

........

```
str.replace(new RegExp('\\$', 'g'), '_');
```

Becaue `$` is special char in js, you need to escape it.

Comment: The second is wrong on two counts, it will replace `\$`, not `$` and it will only replace 1 occurrence, not multiple.

Comment: @Andy: Yes, realized it and removed it soon :) Thanks

Answer (score -4):

You don't need regular expressions just to replace one symbol:

```
 newStr = oldStr.replace('$', '_')
```

Comment: The title stated "all" occurrences.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: This will replace just the first occurrence of the symbol, not "all" occurrences. Please remove this answer, as it is plainly wrong