# Find all words that start with "$" and wrap them in a <span> with jQuery/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find a way to search for words beginning with the symbol `$` and wrapping them in `<span></span>` like so:

Current html:

```
<div class="message">$AAPL is awesome.</div>
<div class="message">$MSFT is also awesome.</div>
```

Result I'm after:

```
<div class="message"><span>$AAPL</span> is awesome.</div>
<div class="message"><span>$MSFT</span> is also awesome.</div>
```

I've seen this question here:
[Replace text starting with @ with anchor tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35125135/replace-text-starting-with-with-anchor-tag)

But I'm not sure how to convert it from searching for "@" to "$". I'm confused on the $1 and $2 references in the regex replace.

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: And what research have you done?

Comment: I left of here:

`$(".message:contains('$')").each();` then ran a `.split(' ')` for each and checked if `indexOf '$'` returned `> -1` but not sure if this is the most efficient way

Comment: Maybe this helps (similar question): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748309/find-words-in-html-page-with-javascript

Comment: How can I modify this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35125135/replace-text-starting-with-with-anchor-tag to search for "$" instead? I'm confused with the $1 and $2 references.

Comment: Try [How can I replace all occurrences of a dollar ($) with an underscore (_) in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434413/how-can-i-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-dollar-with-an-underscore-in-java)

Answer (score -2):

What you need is a simple DOM analysis.
You go through the whole document object, and whenever you find the regex `^$`, you put `<span>` at the current location of your iterator, continue until the next   char, and put `</span>` where you are.

Hope this helps